# replace innerhtml string with specific string in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I like to replace any  tag with specific string then print them on console.log

```
var str ='<p><img src=""><img src=""><img src=""><div><img src=""></div><div></div><img src=""><div></div></p>'


var result = $(str).find('img').replaceWith("<$1>")
```

I was expecting something like

```
var str ='<p><$1><$1><$1><div><$1></div><div></div><$1><div></div></p>'
```

Would be great after converting them i like to print the result

Comment: $(str) won't even work because that is not a **valid** selector

Comment: ah.... is there way to bring whole selector then convert them?

Comment: You'll need to add them into the html itself and then do the select thing. You will need `style="display: none;"` for the parent p element to hide them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.html()` and some regexes to get you there. Granted, using regex to read HTML [will always lead to sadness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2672869) but sometimes people still do it in when they have no other option.

```
const originalHtml = $('#some-container').html()

const convertedHtml = originalHtml.replace(/<p>/g, '<foo>').replace(/<\/p>/g, '</foo>')
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcn3ezyu/)